# How can fix it?

Tags: c++, lua

Visual Studio 2013

Lua 5.3.0

How can fix it this error?

```
static const luaL_reg scriptLib[] =
{
    {"Print",       LuaConsolePrint},
    {"WaitSec",     LuaWaitSec},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
```

```
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'scriptLib'
Error   5   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'int'   
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Have you include lua headers ?

Comment: `luaL_reg` does not seem to be defined. Are you missing including a header?

Answer (score 8):

Use `luaL_Reg` instead of `luaL_reg`. (Note the case change.)

In old versions of Lua (until 5.0), the name was `luaL_reg`. It's been `luaL_Reg` for several years now (since 5.1, released in 2006; `luaL_reg` was kept for compatibility in 5.1 but removed in 5.2).

Comment: `luaL_reg` available in *luajit-2.0.4*, but not available since *luajit-2.0.5*.